# Need to click twice in KeyboardAvoidingView even when keyboardshouldpersisttaps is always

Tags: typescript, react-native, formik

I am using a KeyboardAvoidingView to move a button up with the keyboard, within that I have a scrollview which keybordShouldPersistTaps is set to always, within the scrollview, I am using a Formik form. I still have to double click a button twice in order to get the keyboard to dismiss and submit my data. I have always tried to manually dismiss/handle the keyboard on the scrollview with no luck, Any other approaches I should try?

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }} behavior={'padding'}>
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }} keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}>
        <Formik
            initialValues={this.state}
            validationSchema={this.schema}
            onSubmit={(values, actions) => {              
              actions.setSubmitting(false);
            }}
            render={({ handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit, values, isValid }) => {
              return (
                <View style={onboardingStyles.inputContainer}>
                  <View>
                    <Text theme={theme} style={onboardingStyles.headerText}>
                      {i18n.t('phone_verify')}
                    </Text>
                    <TextInput
                      activeHighlight
                      value={RizeCore.util.formatPhoneDOM(values.phone)}
                      onChangeText={(val: string) => {

                        const phone = RizeCore.util.parseOutDigits(val, 10);
                        return handleChange('phone')(phone);
                      }}
                      onBlur={() => handleBlur('phone')}
                      label={i18n.t('phone_number')}
                      style={onboardingStyles.input}
                      labelStyle={{ color: 'white' }}
                      keyboardType={Platform.OS === 'web' ? 'default' : 'number-pad'}
                      returnKeyType="done"
                    />
                  </View>
                  <BottomFixedCTA
                    ctaLabel={i18n.t('phone_send_code')}
                    loading={smsCodeIsBusy}
                    disabled={!isValid}
                    onPress={handleSubmit as undefined}
                    onBackPress={this._navSignUp}
                  />
                </View>
              );
            }}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using:

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: I did try using that, unfortunately to no actual changes

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding parameters to scroolview `keyboardShouldPersistTaps = "handled"`